# add product list of category to newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9

I am very new in Magento so please bear with me..
I want to add a grid of products from single category in my newsletter

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

I tried to add widget it is working but i need to show products from single category but i don't known how to achieve this please help.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried, what you expected and what happend instead. Add screenshots if it helps understanding. Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and DO NOT add a comment.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493630/how-to-allow-multiple-product-selection-in-magento-widget-configuration/34742903#34742903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below block in your newsletter template to display products from specific category, You have to define category id in category_id attribute here.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Here use your own custom template file instead of catalog/product/list.phtml as it will display sorting of page and other things so you can remove that in your template file.

also dont forgot to whitelist this

- Got to system > Permission > Blocks
- Add New Block
- Add catalog/product_list and set Is Allow = Yes

Comment: Thanks it works! please guide me how to create a new template to remove filter and sorting from the template

Comment: You can create a new file in catalog/product/newsletterproductlist.phtml or some thing like this and copy list.phtml code there and remove all unnecessary code which you dont want to display, ( Please mark this answer accepted if it helps you thanks)

Comment: It start working i am very thankful to you please just two things... i remove the pagination but now it only showing 12 products can there be any possibility to define how many products i want to show ? and also i am using grid style but there is no css adding to that so how i add css for that ?

Comment: Hi which version of magento you are using please try with add limit attribute in block if it works if not then make a new phtml file and break the loop after products you wish to display.

Comment: also for css there is a Template Styles below Template Content  so you can add your css there

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.4